# Stripe multiple payment method with difference currency

Tags: php, jquery, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe payment gateway. Let's say product price is USD2000.
Currently my code output 3 payment methods with 1 currency only :

Card : MYR2000

FPX : MYR2000

Alipay : MYR2000

Screenshot here :
[image]

Code :

```
$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    'payment_method_types' => ['card', 'fpx','alipay'],
    'line_items' => [[
        'price_data' => [
            'currency' => 'myr', 'unit_amount' => 8000.00,
            'currency' => 'usd', 'unit_amount' => 2000.00,
            'currency' => 'cny', 'unit_amount' => 4000.00,
            'product_data' => [
                'name' => $productName,
                'metadata' => [
                    'pro_id' => $productID
                ]
            ],
        ],
        'quantity' => 1,
        'description' => $productName,
    ]],
    'mode' => 'payment',
    'success_url' => STRIPE_SUCCESS_URL.'?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
    'cancel_url' => STRIPE_CANCEL_URL,
]);
```

I want to have the 3 payment methods with 3 difference currency as following :

Card : USD2000

FPX : MYR8000

Alipay : CNY4000

How to do that?

Comment: have you tried combing their docs? https://stripe.com/docs/connect/currencies

Comment: If you are looking for a standalone solution, EasyPie lets you accept payments and subscriptions from customers worldwide with a variety of payment methods through Stripe with multicurrency and multilingual support --> https://easypie.shop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do that - you can only set one currency for the Checkout Session.

Comment: how about i create 3 difference checkout session?

Comment: That's how you'd have to do it, but then you'd want to do that each with just the one payment method, and have a way for your user to select the payment method first - maybe use that button to actually redirect to the correct session in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your guide. I have followed your approach to do it.